# django: How to register a python module among the data of a certain model

Tags: python, django

I am not sure if this explanation is easy to understand, anyway I would be happy to get and advice.

I have a model Product and model Source (which describes, the site from which the book was scraped from). And I need to link a self made python module (which is located in same package as Products and Sources but as separate files and takes data from the external websites and puts it into my database).

So for example

```
class Source(models.Model):
    site_name = models.CharField(max_....)
    # module different for each source which is executed separately
    # and gets the data from given source...
    name_Of_module = models.CharField(max_....)
```

In result I want to create a method inside the module which calls the "name_of_module" file, creates correspondent class and calls it's methods...

---

Just in other words, I want to register a module, as string and call afterwords...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want to store a module name in the database which later you want to execute by looking up the module name from the db. If that is correct, you can always dynamically import module using a utility from django:

```
from django.utils.importlib import import_module

class Source(models.Model):
    site_name = models.CharField(max_....)
    # module different for each source which is executed separately
    # and gets the data from given source...
    name_Of_module = models.CharField(max_....)

    def execute_module(self):
        try:
            module = import_module(self.name_Of_module)
        except TypeError:
            # relative import attempted without specifying package
        except ImportError:
            # cant import module
        # get whatever you need within the module
        return getattr(module, 'foo')()
```

If you need to do this, please consider security ramifications. If users are allowed to provide you with the module name, this can introduce security vulnerability. If this is for internal use only, this should be pretty safe.